# How to scroll to the particular div using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to scroll to the particular div using jquery

I have written the code like:

```
 $("#button").on('click',function(){
     var p = $("#dynamictabstrp");
     var offset = p.offset();
     window.scrollBy(offset.left, offset.top);
 });
```

But it is not moving to the div position. How can i do that in jquery or javascript

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this

```
$("#button").on('click',function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        'scrollTop' : $("#dynamictabstrp").position().top
    });
});
```

[.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

Answer (score 17):

Try

[.scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

```
$(window).scrollTop($('#dynamictabstrp').offset().top);
```

---

or

[scrollIntoView()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollIntoView)

```
$('#dynamictabstrp')[0].scrollIntoView(true);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('dynamictabstrp').scrollIntoView(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code :-

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#button").on('click',function(){                
         $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#dynamictabstrp").offset().top
        }, 1000);               
    });
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("#button").click(function(){                
         $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: $("#dynamictabstrp").offset().top
        }, 1000);               
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple script. Change `#targetDiv` with your particular div ID or Class.

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#targetDiv').offset().top
}, 1000);
```

The source code and live demo can be found from here - [Smooth scroll to div using jQuery](http://www.codexworld.com/smooth-scroll-to-div-using-jquery/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set offset as per requirement

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
function secOffset(){
                        jQuery('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: jQuery(window.location.hash).offset().top - 60
                }, 0);
        }
});
```